# ASP.Net VB javascript function: calculate height of content passed to iFrame

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

I'm trying to convert an old ASP.Net 1.0 application to ASP.Net 3.5 and am running into trouble with a JavaScript function.  The application passes in content into an  within a table cell.  The function is supposed to calculate the height of the content and size the table cell appropriately.

Perhaps you can suggest an easier way of accomplishing this with the

**JavaScript function**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
    function calcHeight() {
        var the_height = document.getElementById('iframeWindow').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        document.getElementById('iframeWindow').style.height = the_height;
    }
</script>
```

**Table Cell:**

```
<td valign="top" width="390" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border: #998b7d 1px solid;">
                            <iframe id="iframeWindow" src="promo.aspx" frameborder="0" height="600" width="390"
                                scrolling="no" onload="calcHeight();"></iframe>
                        </td>
```

Comment: changing the server side language version is breaking client side javascript?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  JavaScript code should be robust if code is compliant ....?

Comment: Your question implies that moving from .NET 1.0 to 3.5 has broken your JavaScript, which would be very strange since the JavaScript runs on the client browser, not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that that way. Instead, add script to promo.aspx, that calculates the height of its content (well, body), then have that script call the page where the TD is defined. Note that you will not be able to do this unless both pages are on the same protocol and hostname (for security reasons, conversation between IFRAME's and pages hosting them is blocked).

Alternatively, from your calcHeight, call a function defined in promo.aspx, which would then do the same: calculate the size of its body, and return the value.

Comment: @Susan That's the safety issue... Before you do anything radical, try to use pseudo-protocol `javascript:` in `onload`-attribute. If it does not help, Hari's answer will work for sure.

Comment: @Susan Do like Hari says. Getting properties from `iFrame` is forbidden even locally run HTA.